# Assume |f(z)| is constant for all z in $\Omega$ then f is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here's what I got so far: Let $f(z)=f(x,y)=x+iy$.  If $|f(z)|$ is constant then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=C$, a constant.

I know that in the very end I need to show that $y=0$ for $f$ to be a constant $x$.  How would I get there?

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be holomorphic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful. Unless $f(z) = z$, you cannot write $f(z) = f(x,y) = x + iy$. Instead, let $f = u + iv$, where $u = u(x,y)$ and $v = v(x,y)$. I'm assuming you mean $f$ is analytic on a domain $\Omega$. If $|f|$ is $0$, then $f = 0$. So suppose $|f|$ is a nonzero constant. By the Cauchy Riemann equations, $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. Since $u^2 + v^2$ is constant, differentiating with respect to $x$ yields $u u_x + v v_x = 0$. Similarly, $u u_y + v v_y = 0$, i.e., $-u v_x + v u_x = 0$. Hence $$0 = (u u _x + v v_x)^2 + (-u v_x + v u_x)^2 = u^2(u_x^2 + v_x^2) + v^2(v_x^2 + u_x^2) = (u^2 + v^2)(u_x^2 + v_x^2).$$ Since $u^2 + v^2$ is a nonzero constant, we have $$u_x^2 + v_x^2 = 0,$$ forcing $u_x = v_x = 0$ and hence $u_y = v_y = 0$. Since $u_x = u_y = 0$, $u$ is constant. Similarly, $v$ is constant. Therefore $f = u + iv$ is constant.